# Disable android device encryption in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source

I have a somehow complicated question and I can't find a good source to find the answer to it.

I'm working with AOSP Android 11 and I have full access to the code and can modify literally everything. I have to find a way to prevent the OS to encrypt the device as I need full access to the userdata partition without any restrictions (I want to transfer the user data from one phone to another).

I searched around but it seems that no one has done that.

Any leads or documentation will be useful. Thanks.

P.S - I know about the security issues and the encryption is important but I don't care about that at the moment :D